# Sum values from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have defined a variable called Total which is a Array like this:

```
Var Total[{"SubTotal":9000},{"SubTotal":20000},{"SubTotal":14000}]
```

I want to sum values 9000, 20000, 14000

Comment: What did you tried already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
var total = Total.map(function(object) { return object.SubTotal; })
                 .reduce(function(prevSum, nextNum) { return prevSum + nextNum; });
```

Comment: That's correct, but avoid one-liners for clarity.

Comment: Why not just skip the map and `return prevSum + nextNum.SubTotal;`?

Comment: @MaxArt thanks,  I edited it a little bit

Comment: A small question is Object.map an es6 method

Comment: @Gavin absolutely, but using `map()` makes you 200% cooler :)

Comment: @Geeky `Total` is an `array`, and `map` is a function for arrays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Dummy Haha absolutely. I was just curious as to why you were using it. Still gave you the +1.

Comment: @Gavin If you want to remove `map`, then you have to pass `0` as the second argument of `reduce`.

Comment: @MaxArt Yes, but still one less function call and less code.

Comment: thanks @Dummy it works

Comment: Or, with arrow functions:  `var total = Total.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.SubTotal, 0)`

Comment: @HarryPehkonen arrow functions don't work in older browsers